# Is there a mapping from JVM version to JRE/JDK version?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to decide if I need to explicitly set the JDK version that I used for my build in the manifest file.

I have a default MANIFEST file that tells me :

> Created-By: 19.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

That is the JVM version. But is it enough? Is there a mapping somewhere that will tell me what java version was used for the build?

I'm building with JDK 6 update 24 and I'm using Maven and the ANT plugin is generating that value.

### EDIT

If I look at the built jars I have this:

```
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
```

But when I repackage everything for obfuscation purposes I end up running ANT plugins within Maven that produce "19.1-b02".

Comment: When I create a jar file using the `jar` command of, e.g. jdk 1.7.0_40, it contains a manifest entry saying `Created-By: 1.7.0_40 (Oracle Corporation)`. However, I don’t know why to bother with that attribute, it has no real meaning.

Comment: My case: maybe I've worked to much C++ but, I would like to know what compiler was used to build the jar file. For old legacy clients, we need to mix and match jar files, so we need to use the same compiler. In this case jdk6u24, I just did not want to bother drilling down the issue if I can get the jdk version from what I have.

Comment: There’s no guaranty that the tool packaging the jar ran with the same jdk/jre version than the compiler. And the compiler might have been run with the `-target` option to produce classes for older jre versions. And the jar may got repacked by another tool. Etc. You might check the class file’s version to find out against which target they were compiled. But I’m not sure whether this really helps deciding whether certain legacy hacks are useful. The developer might have created a  software compiled to be compatible with older versions but be still aware of how to do things correctly for newer…

Comment: My evil master plan is simply to GIT branch all releases, and in a few years, if we need to, we can rebuild the software with the same compiler. I'll dump the jdk version in the manifest then.